# Maven maven-assembly-plugin jar-with-dependencies exclude LICENSE.txt from final jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am using Maven to pack a single executable jar and I can't seem to figure out how to make it not put the LICENSE.txt and NOTICE.txt files inside it. These files are found inside the final executable .jar, but I have no such files in my project directory.

I tried multiple configurations that didn't work. The one I am at now is the following:

Inside my pom.xml I have:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>                
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>README*</exclude>
                    <exclude>LICENSE*</exclude>
                    <exclude>NOTICE*</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>                    
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>maven-assembly-plugin</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I also tried using inside the pom.xml

```xml
<descriptors>
    <descriptor>/src/assembly/src.xml</descriptor>
</descriptors>
```

instead of

```xml
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>README*</exclude>
                    <exclude>LICENSE*</exclude>
                    <exclude>NOTICE*</exclude>
                </excludes>
```

with the content of /src/assembly/src.xml:

```xml
        <assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
            <id>distribution</id>
            <formats>
                <format>jar</format>
            </formats>
            <fileSets>
                <fileSet>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>README*</exclude>
                        <exclude>LICENSE*</exclude>
                        <exclude>NOTICE*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <!--useDefaultExcludes>false</useDefaultExcludes-->
                </fileSet>
            </fileSets>
        </assembly>
```

but for this I am getting `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (maven-assembly-plugin) on project DatabaseTaseng: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive distribution: A zip file cannot include itself -> [Help 1]`

How should I configure it to get a single executable jar with dependencies without those .txt files?

Comment: Where do those files live in your project?

Comment: I don't have them. The plugin seems to create them when doing the packing or is getting them from some dependencies. Don't know which of them.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure I believe you :-)  Open the files - what is the content? Presumably the README.txt file will contain clues.

Comment: Sorry, no README.txt file, only LICENSE.txt and NOTICE.txt. LICENSE.txt contains the Apache License Version 2.0, January 2004 and NOTICE.txt `NOTICE file corresponding to section 4(d) of the Apache License, Version 2.0, in this case for the Apache XmlBeans distribution.`. I am using org.apache.poi.poi-ooxml as a dependency. Could these be unpacked from it and left in the root of the archive?

Comment: Yeah, that's quite possible. And you'd probably be in violation of the license agreement if you remove those files. I suggest you leave them!

Comment: I understand, but it's confusing that it puts them in the root of the archive and it may lead people into thinking that this is how you license your program.

Comment: The point in this case is you should use the maven-shade-plugin instead where you can control more things in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The exclusions tag is to exclude jars dependencies. 
The dependencySet tag allows for an [unpackOptions](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_unpackOptions) which has the options to include/exclude files when the dependencies are being unpacked. 
So your assembly should look something like:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
   <!-- TODO: a jarjar format would be better -->
   <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
   <formats>
      <format>jar</format>
   </formats>
   <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
   <dependencySets>
      <dependencySet>
         <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
         <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
         <unpack>true</unpack>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
         <unpackOptions>
            <excludes>
               <exclude>**/README.txt</exclude>
            </excludes>
         </unpackOptions>
      </dependencySet>
   </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use filesets...

I use this configuration, taken from here:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html

```
 <assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
     <id>distribution</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <files>
    <file>
      <source>README.txt</source>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <filtered>true</filtered>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>LICENSE.txt</source>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>NOTICE.txt</source>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <filtered>true</filtered>
    </file>
  </files>
 </assembly>
```

This configuration should filter file you need at the moment of the generation of the ouput jar...so,  it should filter also files that will be generated...

I hope this works for you...